# Updating column1 in table1 only if matched column3 in table2

Tags: oracle

I want to update column1 in table1 only if the column2 in table1 match the column3 in table2.

I am trying to do using this query but I got an error that says that I am missing equal sign.

Can anyone can help?

```
update schema1.table1 
set schema1.table1.column1
where schema1.table1.column2 = table2.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says it all. You are not assigning any value to the column. Try to set the value using the equal `=` sign

You may try this:

```
update schema1.table1 
set schema1.table1.column1 = //The value which you want to store
where schema1.table1.column2 = table2.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the error message, you have missed an `=` and not assigning any value for `schema1.table1.column1` in the query.

Try like this:

```
UPDATE schema1.table1 
SET    schema1.table1.column1 = <your_value>
WHERE  schema1.table1.column2 = table2.column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
update schema1.table1 t1 
set t1.column1 = (select t2.columnX from table2 t2
                  where t1.column2 = t2.column1)
where t1.column2 in (select column1 from table2)
```